# writing a simple text file with no key value pair to cloud storage storage

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

My requirement is to export the data from BQ to GCS in a particular sorted order which I am not able to get using automatic export and hence trying to write a manual export for this.
File format is like below:

```
HDR001||5378473972abc||20101|182082||
DTL001||436282798101|
DTL002||QS
DTL005||3733|8
DTL002||QA
DTL005||3733|8
DTL002||QP
DTL005||3733|8
DTL001||436282798111|
DTL002||QS
DTL005||3133|2
DTL002||QA
DTL005||3133|8
DTL002||QP
DTL005||3133|0
```

I am very new to this and am able to write the file in local disk but I am not sure how I can write this to  file to GCS. I tried to use the write_to_file but I seem to be missing something.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle as pkl
import tempfile
from google.colab import auth
from google.cloud import bigquery, storage
```

#import cloudstorage as gcs
auth.authenticate_user()

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=job)

sc = storage.Client(project='temp-project')
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', buffering=- 1,prefix='test',suffix='temp') as fh:
    with open(fh.name,'w+',newline='') as f:
        dfAsString = df.to_string(header=" ", index=False)
        fh.name = fh.write(dfAsString)
        fh.close()

bucket = sc.get_bucket('my-bucket')
target_fn = 'test.csv'
source_fn = fh.name
destination_blob_name = bucket.blob('test.csv')

bucket.blob(destination_blob_name).upload_from_file(source_fn)
```

Can someone please help?

Thank You.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#exporting_data_to_csv_format

Comment: You are using ````w+b```` mode while trying to upload a text file (csv). ````w+b```` is for binary files. Use ````w+t```` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to upload an object through a Cloud Storage bucket. Instead of `upload_from_file`, you need to use `upload_from_filename`. Your code should look like this:

```
bucket.blob(destination_blob_name).upload_from_filename(source_fn)
```

Here are links for the documentation on how to [upload an object to Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-upload-file#storage_upload_file-python) and [Client library](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_filename) docs.

**EDIT:**

The reason why you're getting that is because somewhere in your code, you're passing a Blob object, rather than a String. Currently your destination variable is a Blob Object, change it to String instead:

```
destination_blob_name = bucket.blob('test.csv')
```

to

```
destination_blob_name = 'test.csv'
```

Comment: Thank you however when I try upload_from_file or upload_from_filename, I get the error ValueError: <Blob: my-bucket, temp-project/my-bucket/test.csv, None> could not be converted to unicode

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check.